# What is the best way to make an Android TV menu?

Tags: android, android-tv, television

I'm currently developing an Android TV app.  I find it challenging because you can't just draw a list and have the user navigate with touch.  You have to programmatically scroll the list when the user hits the Dpad buttons.

I would like to create a list that is similar to the menus in the Settings screen on Android TV.  Please see the video [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvhrrh7wy8jj2s4/device-2016-12-08-111314.mp4?dl=0).

So far, the solution I'm using is to create horizontal `RecyclerView` that updates when the user hits dpad right or left.

So in my `adapter` I have a method:

```
 public void incrementPosition() {
      if(currentSelection < getItemCount()) {
          previousSelection = currentSelection;
          notifyItemChanged(previousSelection);
          currentSelection++;
          notifyItemChanged(currentSelection);
      }
 }
```

Then when `onBindViewHolder` is called I have something like:

```
if(position == currentSelection) {
         //draw item to look like it's selected
     }
     else if(position == previousSelection) {
        // draw item to look it's NOT selected
     }
```

This will make the item appear to be selected, however the list doesn't scroll along with the new selection.

```
recentlyAddedRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(currentSelection + 2)
```

(yes, I know `currentSelection` + 2 can go beyond the list, I have some if statements there)

The result is similar to the video posted above. However, it's not as "snappy" as I would like it to be.  I just want to make sure this is the best way to implement it.

And this is a dynamic list from a network call.  So I can't just make a layout with static views.

Comment: Just confirming that you've seen this sample project/library: https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback and this one: https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying the leanback approach.  These sample apps are great until you try to make an app that has a very specific ui.  For example, I'm using a VerticalGridFragment to draw selectable images on the screen.  Now how do I add pagination?  How do I add a dropdown to the top of the layout when I didn't even inflate a layout to begin with?  How do I add images to my sidebar when (again) there is no layout?

Comment: I would think if you are doing pagination & dropdown menus you are doing something wrong or at least not geared toward a Leanback experience - and something not easily navigatable with a d-pad. Two resources to checkout: the Google IO video on the library: https://youtu.be/QFHIfQy8_Wc and Udacity Android TV course: https://www.udacity.com/course/android-tv-and-google-cast-development--ud875B

Comment: Thanks for the links. I watched the Youtube video.  Things still seem very limiting.  You can use styles to customize, but I didn't see anything about how to add other ui elements to your page of cards. I have to add a ViewPager to the top of my page.  Btw, the dropdown is for selecting the season and the sort filter on the shows you are viewing.  I don't think there is a way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [v17.leanback.app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/package-summary.html) libraries are the way to do it - that's what was used in your video. If you creates a fresh TV-only Android Studio Project with it's auto-generated Android Studio TV Activity it will give you a great starting point with tangible examples of header rows, customization, etc.

Just in case:

> 1. Android Studio > File > New Project > name it & click Next
> 2. Only select the TV Platform then click Next
> 3. Select "Android TV Activity" then click Next

You'll care about the `MainFragment` & `CardPresenter`. Think of the `BrowseFragment` as a listview you populate with rows. Rows are filled with Cards which are built-upon `FrameLayouts`. `RecyclerView` is already integrated into leanback... I've found I have to spend a lot of time customizing them as you've noted, and just trying to find/navigate relevant online documentation. Good luck.

Comment: Have you actually used leanback to create a tv app that is similar to HBO Now or Netflix?  My app looks nothing like a leanback demo.  The sidebar needs icons, colors, and animations, the main screen has sort filters, buttons etc.  How do you do this with leanback?  I don't know understand how anyone could make a leanback application that looks like anything beyond the basic demo app.

Comment: yes I have used leanback to create a tv app for such purposes, but yes it can be tricky. Take a look at the leanback showcase if you haven't: https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase (there is a video on youtube also). Beyond that I think you'd have to ask a more specific question than "What is the best way to make an Android TV menu?". Good luck hope things work out for you. p.s. I can't get your mp4 link to work.